# dropdown option printed on multiple lines : error

Tags: javascript, php

In the school project I'm working on, the user can add a row to a table by clicking on a button. I used javascript to do this.
In one column of the table has to come a dropdown. But it has to be filled with a list I get from the controller, so I can access that with PHP.

This is what I have :

[image: code]

It works besides for 1 element. The text is so long that it gets printed on multiple lines en this gives an error.

[image: error]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: why cannot you directly generate select menu in html itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use back ticks instead of single quotes and use as below:

```
var txt = `<?php echo $lijstfeit->lijstfeit ?>`;
option.text = txt.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
```

Answer (score 0):

use json_encode to encode the PHP echo string.

like so:

```
option.text = json_encode(<php echo $variable->text; ?>)
```